# Is there a way to find the Project ID from Google Developer console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-fingerprint-api, developer-console, google-api-console

I am working on one of the app, which we received from our implementation partners. I noticed that, while migration, they were not able to provide the Project ID associated with one of the app. As we have N number of apps in API console (Google Developer Console) I am not able to find the correct Project ID associated with the package name.

I worked on similar issue, and was able to resolve it by navigating via each app in GDC and checking the SHA1 key in the credential page, which in turn will have the package name under : 
Package name
From your AndroidManifest.xml file, just below the Sha 1 key.

However the app above in question doesnot have the Sha1 key. I am wondering if there is a way to get the Project ID from Google Play Console or Google Developer console associated with the Package name.

Comment: One question, is the app online in google-play?

Comment: By Online if you mean its released in Play store, then Yes is the answer. Its released and available in Play store

Comment: for sure you can find the id then. You solved the problem or you need help?

Comment: No I haven't found the solution yet. I had to manually go over each app in the Google API console. If you could help with more details, it would help me in future

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this in general from the Google Play console. However if the App uses Google Play Games Services, then the project id is linked at the bottom of the page for the app in the Play Console.[image: Screenshot of Play Console]

I'm afraid I don't know the answer for the Developer Console, but I suspect there isn't.

Comment: Yes, I do not think there is way. I think Google should make our life simpler by adding the package name to the linked project ID.